# Convergence complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Does this integral converge

$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\frac{e^{Rte^{i\theta}}}{\sqrt{Re^{i\theta}+1}}\cdot iRe^{i\theta}d\theta$$

where t is a positive integer?

If the integral diverges, how can I prove this?

p.s. This integral is part of a larger contour integral to calculate

$$\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty} \frac{e^{zt}}{\sqrt{1+z}} dz$$

I know that

$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\frac{e^{Rte^{i\theta}}}{\sqrt{Re^{i\theta}+1}}\cdot iRe^{i\theta}d\theta + \int_{-\pi}^{\frac{-\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{Rte^{i\theta}}}{\sqrt{Re^{i\theta}+1}}\cdot iRe^{i\theta}d\theta=0$$

Comment: What is $R$? If $R\neq 1$,  you are integrating over a finite domain of $\theta$ and there are no singularities. I feel like what you really want to ask is what happens to the integral as $R\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Sam That is what I mean. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

use $$\left| \frac{e^{Rt e^{i\theta}}}{\sqrt{R e^{i\theta} +1}} iR e^{i\theta}
\right|\leq c\sqrt{R}\, e^{Rt \cos\theta}$$
with an appropriate $c$ for $R\geq R_0$ to show that the integral converges.

Comment: did you use Jordan's Lemma to achieve the bound  also is there anyway to sharpen the bound?

Comment: @Zophikel: no Lemma of Jordan. The inequality simply follows from $|R/\sqrt{R e^{i\theta } + 1}|= \sqrt{R} /|\sqrt{1 +e^{-i\theta} /R}| \leq c \sqrt{R}$ if $R$ is large enough.